# Reset html comments format in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format, comments, settings

I had changed comments format for HTML language in VSCode recently as I was using Twig language.
I had changed it to `{# #}`.
However, I do not remember how I changed it and am unable to reset it to default now.
So whenever I press `ctrl` + `/`, it results into `{# <cursor> #}`.
I need it back to normal now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are working with any language or frame work or any other you should install extension of it so you don't require change manually

Not need to try to back normal only just uninstall & then install vs code

Comment: This is not due to any extension. I have made some changes in configuration and I don't remember where.

Comment: just uninstall & then install vs code

Comment: Hah it did work. Although I still don't know why it happened. I'll mark as answer